# колонка из csv в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

Существует ли способ, взять колонку из csv и просто ручками через pgadmin4 запилить в таблицу? Или придеться писать скрипт?

Comment: `copy`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html Не очень понятно, что есть и что надо получить.

Comment: да не именно не синтаксисом а вот взять нажать на колонку в csv нажать ctrl+c и потом в pgadmin нажать на таблицу и просто в нее вставить эту колонку.

Comment: Ну скрипт допустим это громко сказано. Можно зайти например на sqlfiddle.com, нажать на кнопку "Text to DDL"  и он на основании ваших csv данных сделает `insert` которым это в БД вставлять. В более сложных случаях можно сделать регулярку на regex101.com которая конвертнет входящий текст опять же в набор insert